# How can I use an array to validate an element length from another array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a file validator, so, import a csv file, check the contents, check each field isn't blank, then check the length of each field.  If it's bigger than a specified value (different for each field), then I want to display it as a different colour, so that I can easily identify any fields that won't fit into my database.

I managed to read the file into an array, check that it's not null, and check the field length against a static value.  I have another array containing the field sizes, but I can't seem to get cross reference dataArrayElement 0 with valaidateArrayElement 0.

I've got it outputting to a JTable, and displaying anything that hits "TOOBIG" in a different colour.

```
Integer[] validateLength = {8,2,22,11,25,13,6,2,34,11,35,35,34,11,1};

   class checkValue{
        public String validate(String value){
        // Check to see if the cell is null or blank
        if (StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(value)) {
            return "EMPTY";
        } else if (value.length() > 8) { //Work out how to set this as differing field lengths
            return "TOOBIG";
          }
          else {
            return "OK";
          }
      }
    }


class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6703872492730589499L;
private checkValue cv = new checkValue();

    public JComponent getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        JComponent cellComponent = (JComponent) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (cv.validate(table.getValueAt(row, column).toString()).equals("TOOBIG")){
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.RED);
            cellComponent.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            cellComponent.setToolTipText("Data is too big for the DB");
        } else if(cv.validate(table.getValueAt(row, column).toString()).equals("EMPTY")){
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            cellComponent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            cellComponent.setToolTipText("Field is empty in import file!");
        }  else   {
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            cellComponent.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
          }
        return cellComponent;
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: *"How can I use an array to validate an element length from another array?"* And .. ***what*** do you think that has to do with **Swing**?

Comment: I'm displaying it on a JFrame, and when I created the question, it suggested I add the Swing tag, apologies if this added confusion.

Comment: Pass the index of the field (I'd guess it's `column`) to `validate(String value)` and use that index to access `validateLength` (there are some design issues, but I'll ignore them for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass index of your data element in validate method and check corresponding value from validateLength

```
    Integer[] validateLength = {8,2,22,11,25,13,6,2,34,11,35,35,34,11,1};

    public String validate(String value, int index){
    // Check to see if the cell is null or blank
    if (StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(value)) {
        return "EMPTY";
    } else if (value.length() > validateLength[index]) { 
        return "TOOBIG";
      }
      else {
        return "OK";
      }
  }
```

And while calling this method pass the index (assuming values to validate are across columns)

```
validate(table.getValueAt(row, column).toString(), column);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Perfect, thank you, it's been driving me crazy! :-)
(I can't mark the answer up as I've not got enough reputation, but I've marked it as the answer)

Comment: Glad that helped you .. have fun coding :)